# Why is express-session not setting the cookie to my Remix app in the frontend?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session, remix.run

Backend is not setting the cookie on the frontend. I expected to see a cookie with the name 'connect.sid' but no cookies are found.

Whenever I attempt to authenticate, the backend (Node) throws a 401 as req.user is undefined.

I have also set the withCredentials field set to true in axios from the frontend (Remix) when making the login request as well as the profile request.

```
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  next();
});
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true,
  })
); // Setup cors for cross domain requests
app.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET ?? "thisismysecretkeyfornodejs",
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
); // Use express session middleware
app.use(passport.initialize()); // Initialize passport
app.use(passport.session()); // Using session cookies
```